# What's the recommended way of installing Podman 4 in Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: software-installation, 22.04, container, podman

Ubuntu 22.04 only has [Podman 3.4.4](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/podman) in its repos and [the former PPA for latest Podman was discontinued for 22.04](https://podman.io/getting-started/installation#ubuntu)

> Kubic packages have been discontinued for Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. Current users of the Kubic repos for Ubuntu are highly recommended to uninstall the packages from the Kubic repos before upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.

Therefore I would love to know how to get the current Podman version installed on Ubuntu 22.04 in a sane manner that allows getting updates without having to check and install a binary manually.

Comment: It looks like [Ubuntu 22.10 ships with Podman 3.4.4](https://packages.ubuntu.com/kinetic/admin/podman) as well, so that does not appear to be a way to get podman v 4 either.

Answer (score 10):

The [manual instructions](https://software.opensuse.org//download.html?project=devel%3Akubic%3Alibcontainers%3Aunstable&package=podman) at the moment use a wrong url for the repo key. The following gives you `podman version 4.3.1`:

- Run this script as `root`:

```
#!/bin/sh

ubuntu_version='22.04'
key_url="https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/devel:/kubic:/libcontainers:/unstable/xUbuntu_${ubuntu_version}/Release.key"
sources_url="https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/devel:/kubic:/libcontainers:/unstable/xUbuntu_${ubuntu_version}"

echo "deb $sources_url/ /" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/devel:kubic:libcontainers:unstable.list
curl -fsSL $key_url | gpg --dearmor | tee /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/devel_kubic_libcontainers_unstable.gpg > /dev/null
apt update
apt install podman
```

- Podman `v4` is also available in the Ubuntu `23.10` repos

Comment: Because Ubuntu `podman` has version `100:3.4.2-5` I had to install the specific version I wanted, eg `apt install podman=4:4.3.1-0ubuntu22.04+obs65.14` to use these packages

Comment: Podman 3.4 has number of problems. Running the above update into 4.4 fixes all I had on Ubuntu 22 LTS.

Comment: It worked for me now in Proxmox-7.3-3/lxc-5.0.0/ubuntu-22.04/podman-4.5.0 with `podman run -dt -p 8080:80/tcp docker.io/library/httpd`: It works!

Comment: Is the kubic repo still the recommended way of getting the latest (or at least newer) version of Podman on Ubuntu 22.04?

Comment: @cjt - another option is to upgrade to Ubuntu `23.10` which has `podman 4.3.1` & some new security features for unprivileged user namespaces

Comment: I don't think it's very responsible to tell people to install from a repo without adding any information about who maintains it -- who maintains `devel:/kubic:/libcontainers:/`? The podman developers or is it a community effort? Why are builds only available under `unstable`? I really think this answer needs to be amended to make people understand what they are actually doing and to what extent they can expect it to work in the future -- this is an entirely unsupported third party repo from what I can see.

Comment: @pzkpfw - the Kubic project was an opensuse funded project (now superceded by `MicroOS`) - I added a note about `podman v4` in the Ubuntu repos

Answer (score 1):

You can't install, the recommended version is 3.4

https://podman.io/blogs/2022/04/05/ubuntu-2204-lts-kubic.html

> The package versions available currently are: Podman 3.4, Buildah 1.23
> and Skopeo 1.4.
>
> There won’t be any further updates to the Kubic repos as far as
> Podman, Buildah and Skopeo are concerned, so users are recommended to
> use the default repos on 22.04 LTS.

But you can "Build from Scratch" per:

https://podman.io/getting-started/installation.html#building-from-scratch

There are good instructions specifically for each OS to install dependencies, build dependencies from scratch and build Podman 4 (no point reproducing it all here as its maintained there)

Comment: Well, I know that there's now official PPA any more (I explicitly mentioned this in my post) and I also know that I can build it from scratch (I explicitly mentioned that manually maintaining a binary is _not_ the solution).

Comment: Yea, and I'm still trying to install from scratch.  Currently stuck on cni plugins installation...  but I'm out of time. My options now are stick with 3.4 from the PPA or wipe my OS and install Fedora.  ... Like me, or others in this situation you're probably SOL,  For now unless you or I develop the package we're lookong for this is the answer sorry ... can't help any more.

Comment: There is a repo that is not intended for production use https://github.com/containers/podman/issues/14302#issuecomment-1192617223 .  Quote: _This repo gets the latest upstream podman and other packages soon after upstream release._

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions from https://github.com/containers/podman/issues/14065 include

- Install the Debian package
- Install podman from brew, https://brew.sh/

I installed from brew and I'm happy with the result.